# How To Search In ComboBox With TextBox?

Tags: combobox

I Have a ComboBox With 3 Items (`Room,Class,HighSchool`) And a TextBox.

I Want When i Write `Room` IN TextBox Immediately  Combobox.

```
SelectedItem = Room
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a custom control. I use an intellisense text box that you bind to a list, when you start typing it will automatically select any item in the list with that character.

window xaml below;

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="_Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="textbox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" GotMouseCapture="textbox_GotMouseCapture"
             GotFocus="textbox_GotFocus" PreviewKeyDown="textbox_PreviewKeyDown" TextChanged="textbox_TextChanged"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=intelliWin}"
             Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="{Binding ElementName=intelliWin, Path=Width}" TextAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
    <Popup Name="popup" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinWidth="180" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Bottom"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textbox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Popup">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
        <Grid>
            <ListBox Name="listbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                     MouseUp="listbox_MouseUp" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
            </ListBox>
        </Grid> 
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

to use it in the window you need to do this

```
<local:IntellisenseStyleTextbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding YOUR LIST DATA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="intelliseText" Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>'
```

then add this to the .cs file

```
public partial class IntellisenseStyleTextbox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IntellisenseStyleTextbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<string> PossibleItems { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler ItemSelected;

    protected void OnItemSelected(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = ItemSelected;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    // Bindable Text property from http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValueDp(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Required to allow items to bind to Text property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
            typeof(IntellisenseStyleTextbox), null);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string p = null)
    {
        SetValue(property, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public List<string> GetDisplayedModelNames()
    {
        // Only display items that have the current text at the start of them
        List<string> toDisplay = new List<string>();
        string match = textbox.Text.ToLower();
        foreach (string possibleItem in PossibleItems)
        {
            string lower = possibleItem.ToLower();
            if (lower.Contains(match))
            {
                toDisplay.Add(possibleItem);
            }
        }

        return toDisplay;
    }

    private void textbox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            // Up and down arrow keys move up and down list box
            case Key.Down:
                listbox.SelectedIndex++;
                listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.SelectedItem);
                break;
            case Key.Up:
                // Make sure item is always selected
                if (listbox.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    listbox.SelectedIndex--;
                    listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.SelectedItem);
                }

                break;
            // Enter key fills in OutputName with selected text
            case Key.Enter:
                SelectListBoxItem();
                break;
            case Key.Back:
                popup.IsOpen = true;
                break;
        }

        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }

    private void SelectListBoxItem()
    {
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        List<string> outputNames = GetDisplayedModelNames();

        if (listbox.SelectedIndex < outputNames.Count)
        {
            this.Text = outputNames[listbox.SelectedIndex];
            // Move caret to end of text
            textbox.CaretIndex = this.Text.Count();
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            OnItemSelected(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void listbox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectListBoxItem();
    }

    private void textbox_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenPopup();
    }

    private void textbox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenPopup();
    }

    private void OpenPopup()
    {
        listbox.ItemsSource = GetDisplayedModelNames();
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(TextProperty, textbox.Text, textbox.Text));
        // Update listbox with relevant names
        if (PossibleItems == null) return;
        listbox.ItemsSource = this.GetDisplayedModelNames();
    }
}
```